# Start and fork screen session from PHP

Tags: php, gnu-screen

How can I make php start GNU Screen and keep it running after the php script has finished executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with:

```
exec("nohup screen -dmS new_name");
```

Albeit `-dmS` should already be sufficient to make screen fork itself into a background process.

Comment: I was already using dmS and I tried with/without nohup and with/without & at the end, none of it worked.

Comment: @Hintswen: It very much depends on your server configuration. If mod_php runs under mod_chroot/jail or php-cgi under a suexec restricted account, you're out of luck.

Comment: Actually I had another look at my script and I made screen run a script in the same folder rather than a command and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Run it with `-dmS` command line arguments, which force it to start as a daemon (ie: immediately detach).

Online docs for the command line args [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Invoking-Screen.html#Invoking-Screen).